# How to use a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, web-services

I have this array generated:

Code:

```
$user_info = file_get_contents('http://localhost/rest-server/webservice/api.php?action=get_user&id='.$_GET["id"]);      
$user_info = json_decode($user_info, true);     
print_r($user_info);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( [user_info] => 
        Array ( [id] => 12 
                [first_name] => Test1 
                [last_name] => User1 
                [email] => user1@example.com 
                [country] => ABC 
                [city] => XYZ 
              )
          )
      )
```

How can I use this array? So that I fetch this data like : `$user_info['first_name'];

I want to put a While Loop on Array for Multiple Records like this too:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_list] => Array ( [id] => 12 [first_name] => Test1 [last_name] => User1 [email] => user1@example.com [country] => ABC [city] => XYZ ) ) [1] => Array ( [user_list] => Array ( [id] => 13 [first_name] => Test2 [last_name] => User2 [email] => user2@example.com [country] => XYZ [city] => ABC ) ) )
```

Comment: This is an array of arrays to to access the first "first_name" you need to reference it by `$user_info[0]["first_name"];`

Comment: I tried it this way but its not working

Comment: What happened? Error? Nothing?

Comment: This is what you need `$user_info[0]["user_info"]["first_name"];`

Comment: OK but what if i have Multiple Records like this :

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_list] => Array ( [id] => 12 [first_name] => Test1 [last_name] => User1 [email] => user1@example.com [country] => ABC [city] => XYZ ) ) [1] => Array ( [user_list] => Array ( [id] => 13 [first_name] => Test2 [last_name] => User2 [email] => user2@example.com [country] => XYZ [city] => ABC ) ) )

Comment: Where i have to put a loop on Array. what in that case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is given as multi-dimensional array.

You can try to access it like so:

```
// Update to go through all items in $user_info:
foreach ($user_info as $index => $value)
{
    echo "For item {$index}:\n",
         "First name is: {$value['user_info']['first_name']}\n",
         "Email is     : {$value['user_info']['email']}\n";
    // etc.
}


// Old post to print individual record:

// Print the first name:
echo $user_info[0]['user_info']['first_name'];

// Print the email:
echo $user_info[0]['user_info']['email'];

// etc.
```

Links for your reference:

1. [PHP.net on array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
2. [PHP.net on foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Well this worked for single record but not for a multiple records like this:

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_list] => Array ( [id] => 12 [first_name] => Test1 [last_name] => User1 [email] => user1@example.com [country] => ABC [city] => XYZ ) ) [1] => Array ( [user_list] => Array ( [id] => 13 [first_name] => Test2 [last_name] => User2 [email] => user2@example.com [country] => XYZ [city] => ABC ) ) )

Comment: Didn't know you have more than one item in your output. I have updated the answer above. For information, please see: [PHP.net on array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [PHP.net on foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($yourArray as $array) {
    echo $array['user_info']['first_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this ?

```
echo  $user_info[0]['first_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo $user_info[0]['user_info']['id'] 
 echo $user_info[0]['user_info']['first_name']
 echo $user_info[0]['user_info']['last_name'] 
 echo $user_info[0]['user_info']['email']
 echo $user_info[0]['user_info']['country'] 
 echo $user_info[0]['user_info']['city']
```

It gives you output like below with particular array value.

- 12
- Test1
- User1
- user1@example.com
- ABC
- XYZ

It is for perticular this array if you want to fetch array that is position on [1] then you must use `foreach`.